# How to set fallback value to English on .net application resources

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, localization, resources

We have a project were we have `Resources.resx`, `Resources.fr.resx` and `Resources.de.resx`.

Let's say the application is set to use Swiss German `de-CH`. When a string resource is missing for german language I want to see that string in English in my application.

Doing several tests we have noticed that when a string is missing the fallback language string value is set to the system language value.

For example if my german string is missing I want it to being shown in english, but it is being shown in french, which is my windows current language.

Our application is an UWP application.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to solve it?

EDIT:

I made several tests changing my system culture:

- OS (windows) culture english and UWP language fallback value to french: missing translations for german are being set in french.
- OS (windows) culture spanish and UWP language fallback value to english: missing translation for german are being set in english.
- **OS (windows) culture swiss french and UWP language fallback to english: missing translations for german are being set in french which is OS language.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Localization .NET; Fallback language when using ResourceManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272744/localization-net-fallback-language-when-using-resourcemanager)

Comment: Please check if your app's default language is en-US where in the package manifest file. for more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest)

Comment: Why ever keep missing strings? Just fill them all with appropriate values.

Comment: We are working with a professional german translator because we dont have the proper knowledge to translate this strings by ourselves. Since we are receiving new translated strings each month, we need to fallback the strings which are not traduced yet to english which is the default application language.

Comment: For example if my german string is missing I want it to being shown in english, but it is being shown in french, which is my windows current language. it is by design,  if missing translation, it will set the default base on your system.

Comment: No, it does not solve the issue. That is why it is not marked as accepted.

Comment: Any updates? please feel free post your result,  I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

> For example if my German string is missing I want it to being shown in English, but it is being shown in French, which is my windows current language.

It is by design, if you have not specific app's language, and if miss translation, it will set the default language base on your system(app contains resource matched with system). And if you app does not contain the language that matched with system. it will direct to app's default language in the app's package manifeat file.

If you want to set the default as English when missing translation, you could set the app's default language as `en`.

[image]

For more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest), and here is official code sample that you could [refer](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ApplicationResources).